# modulus of 2 in power

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How can we find $2^{75} ( \text{mod} \ 73)$ opening $2^{75}$ is leading to a very large decimal number.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's theorem?

Comment: If you don't know Fermat's little theorem, or not sure if $73$ is a prime, [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) would still be manageable by hand.